# How to convert data captured every 10 min interval into 15 min interval data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with below data ( Average of the values of timestamp 7.50 and 7.40 should be my value of A for time Stamp 7.45)

```
Date_Time     |         A
7/28/2017 8:00|     443.75
7/28/2017 7:50|     440.75
7/28/2017 7:45|     NA
7/28/2017 7:40|     447.5
7/28/2017 7:30|     448.75
7/28/2017 7:20|     444.5
7/28/2017 7:15|     NA
7/28/2017 7:10|     440.25
7/28/2017 7:00|     447.5
```

I want it to transform into 15 min interval  something like below using mean:

```
Date / Time   |    Object Value
7/28/2017 8:00|        465
7/28/2017 7:45|        464.875
7/28/2017 7:30|        464.75
7/28/2017 7:15|        464.875
7/28/2017 7:00|        465
```

Comment: do you take the value at `7:45` to be the average of values at `7:40` and `7:50`?

Comment: Yes, I want  average of 7.40 and 7.50 to be tagged as 7.45

Comment: I think @Aramis7d is asking you how do you determine the value on 7:45?

Comment: @Tilo I saw you just changed your example input data frame. This is a really bad practice when you changed your input data while others have already worked on your question.

Comment: @Tilo For your new example, `library(imputeTS) dt$A <- na.interpolation(dt$A)` will probably work. After that you can filter out your dataframe based on the 15 minutes interval. but I have not time to update my answer. Please provide clear, good problem statement, reproducible example, and desired output next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updat

The OP changes his or her desired output. Since I have no time to update my answer, I will leave my answer as it is. See my comment in the original post to see how to use `na.interpolation` to fill in the missing values.

#### Original Post

This solution assumes you calculated the average based on the average values in `8:00`, `7:30`, and `7:00`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(imputeTS)


dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(Date.Time = mdy_hm(Date.Time)) %>%
  filter(Date.Time %in% seq(min(Date.Time), max(Date.Time), by = "15 min")) %>%
  complete(Date.Time = seq(min(Date.Time), max(Date.Time), by = "15 min")) %>%
  mutate(Object.Value = na.interpolation(Object.Value)) %>%
  fill(Object.Name) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date.Time))

dt2
# A tibble: 5 x 3
            Date.Time Object.Name Object.Value
               <dttm>       <chr>        <dbl>
1 2017-07-28 08:00:00           a      465.000
2 2017-07-28 07:45:00           a      464.875
3 2017-07-28 07:30:00           a      464.750
4 2017-07-28 07:15:00           a      464.875
5 2017-07-28 07:00:00           a      465.000
```

**Data**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "'Date Time' 'Object Name' 'Object Value'
'7/28/2017 8:00' a 465
                 '7/28/2017 7:50' a 465
                 '7/28/2017 7:40' a 464.75
                 '7/28/2017 7:30' a 464.75
                 '7/28/2017 7:20' a 464.75
                 '7/28/2017 7:10' a 465
                 '7/28/2017 7:00' a 465",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, Just wanted to know how to average below values

Comment: Average of the values of timestamp 7.50 and 7.40 should be my value of A for time Stamp 7.45

Answer (score 0):

If the values measured on the 10-minute intervals are time-integrated averages over that period, it's reasonable to average them to a different period.  If these are instantaneous measurements, then it's more reasonable to smooth them as others have suggested.

To take time-integrated averages measured on the 10-minute schedule and average those to the 15-minute schedule, you can use the intervalaverage package:

```r
library(data.table)
library(intervalaverage)
x <- structure(list(time = c("7/28/2017 8:00", "7/28/2017 7:50", "7/28/2017 7:45", 
                             "7/28/2017 7:40", "7/28/2017 7:30", "7/28/2017 7:20", "7/28/2017 7:15", 
                             "7/28/2017 7:10", "7/28/2017 7:00"), A = c(443.75, 440.75, NA, 
                                                                        447.5, 448.75, 444.5, NA, 440.25, 447.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                 -9L), class = "data.frame")
y <- structure(list(time = c("7/28/2017 8:00", "7/28/2017 7:45", "7/28/2017 7:30", 
                             "7/28/2017 7:15", "7/28/2017 7:00")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(x)
setDT(y)

x
#>              time      A
#> 1: 7/28/2017 8:00 443.75
#> 2: 7/28/2017 7:50 440.75
#> 3: 7/28/2017 7:45     NA
#> 4: 7/28/2017 7:40 447.50
#> 5: 7/28/2017 7:30 448.75
#> 6: 7/28/2017 7:20 444.50
#> 7: 7/28/2017 7:15     NA
#> 8: 7/28/2017 7:10 440.25
#> 9: 7/28/2017 7:00 447.50
y
#>              time
#> 1: 7/28/2017 8:00
#> 2: 7/28/2017 7:45
#> 3: 7/28/2017 7:30
#> 4: 7/28/2017 7:15
#> 5: 7/28/2017 7:00

x[, time:=as.POSIXct(time,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',tz = "UTC")]
setnames(x, "time","start_time")
x[, start_time_integer:=as.integer(start_time)]

y[, time:=as.POSIXct(time,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',tz = "UTC")]
setnames(y, "time","start_time")
y[, start_time_integer:=as.integer(start_time)]

setkey(y, start_time)
setkey(x, start_time)


##drop time times at 15 and 45
x <- x[!start_time %in% as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-28 07:45:00","2017-07-28 07:15:00"),tz="UTC")]


x[, end_time_integer:=as.integer(start_time)+60L*10L-1L]
x[, end_time:=as.POSIXct(end_time_integer,origin="1969-12-31 24:00:00",tz = "UTC")]


y[, end_time_integer:=as.integer(start_time)+60L*15L-1L]
y[, end_time:=as.POSIXct(end_time_integer,origin="1969-12-31 24:00:00",tz = "UTC")]


x
#>             start_time      A start_time_integer end_time_integer
#> 1: 2017-07-28 07:00:00 447.50         1501225200       1501225799
#> 2: 2017-07-28 07:10:00 440.25         1501225800       1501226399
#> 3: 2017-07-28 07:20:00 444.50         1501226400       1501226999
#> 4: 2017-07-28 07:30:00 448.75         1501227000       1501227599
#> 5: 2017-07-28 07:40:00 447.50         1501227600       1501228199
#> 6: 2017-07-28 07:50:00 440.75         1501228200       1501228799
#> 7: 2017-07-28 08:00:00 443.75         1501228800       1501229399
#>               end_time
#> 1: 2017-07-28 07:09:59
#> 2: 2017-07-28 07:19:59
#> 3: 2017-07-28 07:29:59
#> 4: 2017-07-28 07:39:59
#> 5: 2017-07-28 07:49:59
#> 6: 2017-07-28 07:59:59
#> 7: 2017-07-28 08:09:59
y
#>             start_time start_time_integer end_time_integer            end_time
#> 1: 2017-07-28 07:00:00         1501225200       1501226099 2017-07-28 07:14:59
#> 2: 2017-07-28 07:15:00         1501226100       1501226999 2017-07-28 07:29:59
#> 3: 2017-07-28 07:30:00         1501227000       1501227899 2017-07-28 07:44:59
#> 4: 2017-07-28 07:45:00         1501227900       1501228799 2017-07-28 07:59:59
#> 5: 2017-07-28 08:00:00         1501228800       1501229699 2017-07-28 08:14:59
out <- intervalaverage(x,y,interval_vars=c("start_time_integer","end_time_integer"),value_vars="A")

out[, start_time:=as.POSIXct(start_time_integer,origin="1969-12-31 24:00:00",tz="UTC")]
out[, end_time:=as.POSIXct(end_time_integer,origin="1969-12-31 24:00:00",tz="UTC")]
out[, list(start_time,end_time, A)]
#>             start_time            end_time        A
#> 1: 2017-07-28 07:00:00 2017-07-28 07:14:59 445.0833
#> 2: 2017-07-28 07:15:00 2017-07-28 07:29:59 443.0833
#> 3: 2017-07-28 07:30:00 2017-07-28 07:44:59 448.3333
#> 4: 2017-07-28 07:45:00 2017-07-28 07:59:59 443.0000
#> 5: 2017-07-28 08:00:00 2017-07-28 08:14:59       NA


#Note that this just equivalent to taking weighted.mean:

weighted.mean(c(447.5,440.25),w=c(10,5))
#> [1] 445.0833
weighted.mean(c(440.25,444.5),w=c(5,10))
#> [1] 443.0833
#etc
```

Note that the intervalaverage package requires integer columns defining closed intervals, hence the conversion to integer. integers are converted back to datetime (POSIXct) for readability.